# How to add timestamps to lines of a cronjob output and redirect stdout and stderr to different processes and/or files

Tags: bash, cron, sh

I've spent several hours with this - adding timestamps to output lines of cronjobs and redirecting stdout and stderr to separate processes for that, and then to separate files, stumbling upon several pitfalls. So, I've decided to share my knowledge with people out there, as a recipe.

Answer (score 0):

So, the code is the following, and I will explain peculiarities further:

#### `crontab sample`

```
MAILTO=""

* * * * * ((/home/ilya/stdoutanderr.sh | ts "\%FT\%T\%z:" >> /srv/data/log/ilya-test-crontab-ts/stdout.log) 2>&1 | ts "\%FT\%T\%z:" >> /srv/data/log/ilya-test-crontab-ts/ts-stderr.log) 2>&1 | logger -t CRONOUT
```

Use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab.

First of all, `MAILTO=""` line is used to suppress mailing the cron output. If you're not reading these mails - it's better to suppress it.

Then you see the sample of a cronjob, where `stdoutanderr.sh` is the cronjob itself, the rest is needed for timestamping, logging stderr and stdout separately and outputting any errors with the command itself to syslog.

#### `stdoutanderr.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Sample stdout at " $(date)
echo "Sample stderr at " $(date) >&2
```

As you can see, the sample job jus outputs one line to stderr and another to stdout, nothing fancy here.

`ts` is an utility from `moreutils` package, you should have it installed to use this approach (or you can mock it as a function - there are examples in the net), the stdout of the job is piped into it and then appended to the designated file. All this happens in parenthesis, so at the output of the parenthesis we have just the stderr.

Here comes the first tricky part I didn't know about - one has to additionally escape `%` symbols in the cronjob command lines, otherwise the rest of the line turns into input to the command, so at best it won't run as intended. As you can see - the `%` symbol in the `ts` format is preceded with a backslash.

Otherwise, the format for time is proven to be robust and informative, and turns into the following:

```
2021-12-02T12:25:01+0000: Sample stdout at  Thu Dec 2 12:25:01 UTC 2021
```

One can play with the format and add the subsecond time resolution, or whatewer one needs. Just remember to escape percent symbols in the cron.

Then for the ease of the case we redirect stderr to stdout to pipe it to another `ts` invocation and append to another file. This is achieved by the redirection `2>&1`. Be warned, though, that crontab runs with dash, not bash, and `|&` just won't work as expected, so use the long redirection.

Then the outer parenthesis are closed and the remains of the output, which should only exist if the dash couldn't process the command, will land to cron.log or syslog under the tag of `CRONOUT`. Haven't tested this paragraph, though. If you left mails enabled and/or other means of crontab logging - you probably do not need this one.

Have fun!